# Are unboxed tagged types safe?

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-2.11, scalaz7

I've recently heard about unboxed tagged types in scala and while I was trying to learn how exactly it works, I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26131145/scalaz-unboxed-tagged-type-not-automatically-unboxed) that points to problems the implementation in scalaz had. One of the consequences of the fix was having to explicit unwrap the tagged type:

```
def bmi(mass: Double @@ Kg, height: Double @@ M): Double =
  Tag.unwrap(mass) / pow(Tag.unwrap(height), 2)
```

Then I considered the original idea, where I could do something like:

```
type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
type @@[T, U] = T with Tagged[U]

trait Kilogram
trait Meter
type Kg = Double @@ Kilogram
type M = Double @@ Meter

def bmi(mass: Kg, height: M): Double = mass / pow(height, 2)
```

So now I'm wondering whether the issues found previously in scalaz are specific to it's approach, or if the simple implementation could also have  problems with erasure, arrays or varargs. The thing is I'm still learning scala, so my understanding of it's type system is quite limited and I couldn't figure it out by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unsafe from a type safety perspective. `T @@ U` is a subtype of `T` and an instance of `T @@ U` may be used where ever an instance of `T` is required, even when it is accidental. Consider the following

```
type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
type @@[T, U] = T with Tagged[U]
object Tag {
  def apply[@specialized A, T](a: A): A @@ T = a.asInstanceOf[A @@ T]
}

trait Compare[A] { def compare(a1: A, a2: A): Int }

def useCompare[A: Compare](l: List[A]): Option[A] = 
  l.foldLeft(Option.empty[A])((xs, x) => 
    xs.fold(Some(x))(xxs => 
      if (implicitly[Compare[A]].compare(xxs, x) <= 0) Some(xxs) 
      else Some(x)))

implicit def intCompare: Compare[Int] = new Compare[Int] {
  def compare(a1: Int, a2: Int): Int = 
    a1.compareTo(a2)
}

trait Max
implicit def intCompareMax: Compare[Int @@ Max] = new Compare[Int @@ Max] {
  def compare(a1: Int @@ Max, a2: Int @@ Max): Int = 
    a1.compareTo(a2) * -1
}

scala> val listInts: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
listInts: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val min = useCompare(listInts)
min: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> val listIntMaxs: List[Int @@ Max] = listInts.map(Tag[Int, Max])
listIntMaxs: List[@@[Int,Max]] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val max = useCompare(listIntMaxs)
max: Option[@@[Int,Max]] = Some(4)
```

OK, everything is cool, right? This is why `T @@ U` exists. We want to be able to make a new type and define new type classes for it. Unfortunately, everything isn't ok when your coworker comes along and performs some valid refactoring and accidentally breaks your business logic.

```
scala> val max = useCompare(listIntMaxs ::: List.empty[Int])
max: Option[Int] = Some(1)
```

Oops

In this case, the use of subtyping, combined with the covariance on the `List[+A]` type parameter caused a bug. A `List[Int @@ Max]` may be substituted wherever a `List[Int]` is needed.

Comment: That's true and it could definitely happen even though the coworker should `::: List.empty[Int @@ Max]`. But it's not a bug because of unboxed tagged types, simple subtyping would cause it too, so I'm gonna look for something else for a while.

Comment: Adding `::: List.empty[Int @@ Max]` instead of `::: List.empty[Int]` will not cause the bug. I think you may not be understanding what is happening here. The problem occurs because we are using subtyping to generate a new type in order to redefine type classes for it. You're correct that simple subtyping would cause it too, which is exactly the problem. Imagine if it were possible to define `class MaxInt extends Int` and then replace `Int @@ Max` with `MaxInt` in my example above. This is essentially the same thing.

Comment: You're example of bmi is not a good example of why you would use this pattern. See examples included with the source. I modeled my example from `Max` https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/example/src/main/scala/scalaz/example/TagUsage.scala#L76-L79

Comment: I've played around with scalaz and now I think I fully understand your point. The problem is we were talking about two different usages for tagged types. While I was just looking for a convenient way of not mixing arguments of the same type, but different concepts, your example is closer to monoids. I've looked into the library just not to reinvent the wheel, and that bug made me wonder whether I should use unboxed tagged types for something not essential. Thanks.